# Wix toolkit Executing after another Custom Action

Tags: wix

Here's the list of my custom actions

```
  <CustomAction Id="LaunchApp" Directory="INSTALLDIR" Return="ignore" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /C start somefile.exe" />
            <CustomAction Id="CloseApp" Directory="LocalAppDataFolder" Return="ignore" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]taskkill.exe /F /IM app.exe /t" />
            <CustomAction Id="LaunchUninstallPrompt" Directory="dir3D8C2B6BEC447DDCC50D1386BD4CD865" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /C start /wait %LOCALAPPDATA%/runtime/bin/java -jar" Return="check" Impersonate='no'/>
            <CustomAction Id="DeleteOldSomeFile" Directory="LocalAppDataFolder" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /C IF EXIST %LOCALAPPDATA%\someproj (
            del %LOCALAPPDATA%\someproj\*.* /s /q
        rmdir %LOCALAPPDATA%\someproj /s /q
    )" Return="ignore"/>
```

and here's my install current sequence

```
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="CloseApp" Before="InstallValidate" />
            <Custom Action="LaunchApp" After="InstallFinalize">NOT REMOVE</Custom>
            <Custom Action="LaunchUninstallPrompt" Before="InstallValidate">REMOVE AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I want the Action 'DeleteOldSomeFile' to be executed right after "CloseApp" How would I specify that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sequence number instead of Before/After attributes:

```
<Custom Action="CloseApp" Sequence="1398" />
<Custom Action="DeleteOldSomeFile" Sequence="1399" />
```

You can set "before" dependencies like this:

```
<Custom Action="CloseApp" Before="DeleteOldSomeFile" />
<Custom Action="DeleteOldSomeFile" Before="InstallValidate" />
```